# Hibernation does not work, but what are my alternatives?

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, hibernate

A lot of people face the problem that **hibernation does not work on common hardware devices that where designed for other OSes**. Imho it is one of the most important issues that should be faced by developers since the lack of hibernation mode can cause serious data loss and hardware damage.

Since there is no software-fix to this problem in sight (as far as I know) I would like to ask you, what my alternatives could be and **how to work around the problem of missing hibernation mode**.

One of the main problems for me is the "*ups-I-forget-my-laptop-was-not-connected-with-the-power-adapter*"-moment e.g. when I come back from lunch and the laptop is shutdown because battery reached 0% (and all unsaved data has to be recovered).

I would welcome **any pragmatic solutions from "stick a note to your laptop to remind you of your adapter" to existing software or self-made scripts** that might alarm me or deliver a workaround (e.g. enter in sleepmode when battery is 15%) or similar. Automatic solutions that don't require my unreliable mental fitness are preferred however.

Comment: "the lack of hibernation mode can cause serious data loss and hardware damage." - Uhm... no. Why would you think so? And the power settings offer to suspend on critical battery. Hibernation is going to die out nowadays anyway, as RAM size is getting bigger and bigger. I have 12GB RAM for example and I'm probably rebooting faster than writing all that to the disk would be. Not to mention that I would have to permanently reserve over 12 GB of disk space just to occasionally be able to hibernate.

Comment: I'm no  expert but see this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/6863/what-damage-will-powering-down-instead-of-shutting-down-do)  for a brief discussion on the difference between a proper shutdown and a sudden  power cut regarding possible consequences for soft-and hardware.

Comment: But the fact that you can't hibernate has nothing to do with cutting power. You can let the system suspend or shut down when the battery reaches a critical level.

Comment: thanks. now I know better. that was the alternative I was asking for in my question  : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up your user account to suspend on critical battery level using this terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action suspend
```

Instead of `suspend`, these other actions would also be available: `blank` (screen off), `shutdown`, `hibernate` (if enabled and supported), `interactive` (you will get a pop-up asking you what to do), `nothing` and `logout`.

---

You find out the currently set critical battery charge percentage using the command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical
```

To modify this value, (set to 10% in this example), run a command like that:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 10
```

Comment: can I adjust the "critical battery level"? Because suspend still consumes energy and If it is set too low, I'll face the same problem.

Comment: Sure you can. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "acpitool" to find out the remaining charge percentage:

```
$ acpitool -B|grep 'Remaining'
    Remaining capacity : unknown, 99.37%, 00:00:00
```

Another example script to display a warning pop-up dialog on low battery:

```
LOW=15
X=$(acpitool -B|grep 'Remaining'|sed -e 's/.*capacity : \([a-z]*, \)//' -e 's/%,.*//' -e 's/\..*//') && ([[ $X -lt $LOW ]] && zenity --info --text "Low Batterie: $X Please help !")
```

Comment: I like this idea of desktop notifications and googled around a bit. there is also a tool available for notifications of different battery events : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/ubuntu-battery-monitor-notifications